# C: Problems with the malloc and free method

Tags: c, string, memory

I am trying to write a function called "function", that thakes two strings, named "string1" and "string2" as input and returns another string, named "string" as output. I use the malloc method to generate "string", it does what I expect, but when I later use "free" on "string" I get some error. (Below you find a working example that produces this error.) Could you please explain to me what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>


#define LENGTH_STRING(x)  ((sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))-1)

    
    
char* function(char* string1, int string1_length, char* string2, int string2_length)
{
    char* string = (char*) malloc((string1_length+string2_length+1)*sizeof(char));
    if (!string)
    {
        printf("Memory could not be allocated. \n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < string1_length+string2_length+1; i = i + 1)
        string[i] = 'A';
    string[-1] = '\0';
    return string;
}


int main()
{
    char string1[] = "ABC";
    char string2[] = "XYZ";
    int length_string1 = LENGTH_STRING(string1);
    int length_string2 = LENGTH_STRING(string2);
    char* string = function(string1, length_string1, string2, length_string2);
    printf("%s \n", string);      // I get till here.
    free(string);
    printf("Do I get through here?");  // This does not get printed.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string[-1] = '\0';` Whats this? Array indicies start at 0, `-1` is out of bounds.

Comment: This is not Python, you can't use negative indexes to count from the end.

Comment: `string[-1] = '\0';`?!?!!  What is **that** supposed to do?  You're writing outside the bounds of the array and corrupting memory.

Comment: You want `string[string1_length + string2_length] = '\0'`

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you, this solved my problem.

Comment: `string[i - 1] = 0;`. Do you know `strlen()`?

Comment: `string[-1]` literally means the address which is one less than the &string. If you know how stack grows, it should be out of the valid range of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, you can't subscript with a negative number and expect the last element of the array, as you would in a language like Python.

Writing `arr[i]` in C is equivalent to `*(arr + i)` If we use `arr[-1]` that's equivalent to `*(arr - 1)`. In your case it is accessing memory out of bounds for your array.

If you want to fill a string with `'A'` characters in C, you'd want to iterate from 0 to the length of the string minus *two* to leave space for the null terminating character.

```
for (int i = 0; i < buffer_length - 2; i++) {
    string[i] = 'A';
}

string[buffer_length - 1] = '\0';
```

You might also *not* locally scope `i` to the loop, and then use it after the loop to set the null terminator, as then it will have been incremented to point to the end of the buffer.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < buffer_length - 2; i++) {
    string[i] = 'A';
}
string[i] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 4):

You could save yourself a lot of typing by recognising that `function()` doesn't require the two strings to be passed. And, credit to @yano for `memset()`...

```
char *function( int len1, int len2 ) {
    char *s12 = calloc( len1 + len2 + 1, sizeof *s12 );
    if( s12 )
        memset( s12, 'A', len1 + len2 );
    else
        printf( "Memory alloc failed.\n" );

    return s12;
}
```

`calloc()` will be very fast, and the code leaves the trailing `'\0'`.

---

You could even do the sum when calling `function()`:

```
char *string = function( length_string1 + length_string2 );
```

Then the low level function can be simpler:

```
char *function( int len ) {
    char *s = calloc( len + 1, sizeof *s );
    if( s )
        memset( s, 'A', len );
    else
        printf( "Memory alloc failed.\n" );

    return s;
}
```

Note: it's alright for beginners, but most of those `int`s should actually be declared with the type `size_t`. One step at a time...

Comment: I like this best

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use [`memset`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) instead of rolling your own loop:

```c
#include <string.h>

...

char* function(char* string1, int string1_length, char* string2, int string2_length)
{
   ...
   memset(string, 'A', buffer_length-2);
   string[buffer_length-1] = '\0';
   return string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your version corrected:

```
char* function(char* string1, int string1_length, char* string2, int string2_length)
{
    int size = string1_length + string2_length;
    int i;
    char *string = (char *)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if (!string)
    {
        printf("Memory could not be allocated. \n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        string[i] = 'A';
    string[i] = '\0';
    return string;
}
```

The first thing I did was to make it more readable with size. An error that you made was that you allocated it correctly but then, in the `for` loop, you have ovewritten the null byte space there with a character to then be again replaced with the null byte.

And then, at the end, you can't use -1 as the array index; that's why I did the **int i** on top, so you can still use the `for` loop. In this situation, you can also just use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler + your code:

**RESULT**

> AAAAAAA  Do I get through here?
>
> ...Program finished with exit code 0 Press ENTER to exit console.

If I swap:
**string[-1] = '\0';** ... **string[-1] = 'C';**

**RESULT**

> AAAAAAA double free or corruption (out)
>
> ...Program finished with exit code 0 Press ENTER to exit console.

If I borrow some of your code and rewrite it ...

> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <string.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> char* join(char* s1, char* s2){
> int N = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);
>
> ```
> char* s3 = (char*) malloc(N * sizeof(char));
>
> if (!s3){ //to test do char* s3 = 0;
>     printf("Memory could not be allocated. \n");
>     return 0;
> }
>
> strcpy(s3, s1);
> strcat(s3, s2);
>     
> return s3; }
>
> int main(){
> char str1[] = "ABC";
> char str2[] = "XYZ";
> char* str3 = join(str1, str2);
>
> printf("%s \n", str3);
> free(str3);
> printf("%s \n", str3);
>
> return 0; }
> ```

**RESULT**

> ABCXYZ  �QX
>
> ...Program finished with exit code 0 Press ENTER to exit console.

Looks like on this web page is some block.

You should be able to go out of index array in C but then chaos would happen.

Last char in malloc is **0** or **\0** (auto).